Можно ли защититься от csrf атак без cookies?
Можно ли защититься от csrf атак без cookies?

Нет, нельзя. Потому что куки не могут использоваться в csrf запросах.

Да, можно - если вообще не использовать куки.
Для этого понадобится строго разделить приложение на статическую часть (SPA) и веб-API, и передавать токен/идентификатор сессии/что ещё нужно в каждом запросе к API самостоятельно.

Важный момент что идентификатор сессии надо передавать в хидере. И тут мы изобрели кукис .)  простая сессия подвержена реплай атаке. Защищаясь от неё мы уже изобрели ксрф...

При чём тут вообще не использовать куки?

@eri, но куки браузер будет посылать всегда (ну, уже не всегда, если настроить), а кастомный заголовок послать не даст cors. А какая разница, будет идентификатор сессии в куках или в кастостомном заголовке? Вот для csrf-токена это важно, а для сессии - мне кажется, что нет?

Вот и я говорю что нет разницы в кастомном заголовке и кукис . сложность сопоставимая. Csrf защищает ещё и от повторной отправки формы. Сессия не защищает.
